# Hide controls, if their commands shall not be executed

Tags: c#, wpf

There is an application, which has different permission modes. Depending on the mode, the application has a limited functionality.

Therefore I created my own *RestrictedRoutedUICommand* class, which inherits from *RoutedUICommand* and it knows, when it (the command) is allowed to be executed.

This class *RestrictedRoutedUICommand* has a property *Admission*, which indicates, if it is allowed to execute the command and an event *OnAdmissionChanged* which fires, when this property becomes changed.

The Question is: How can I tell those controls, which do have forbidden commands, to hide, if their command is forbidden?
It should be similar to the functionality of controls turning disabled, if their command can not be executed.

Edit: I don't want to use the *RoutedUICommand.CanExecute()*. Because *CanExecute()* should only determine, if it is possible to execute the command. So I added another method to the *RoutedUICommand* which determines if the command is allowed, I want the controls to use this one.

Comment: Do buttons with forbidden commands already become disabled?

Comment: They only become disabled, if *RoutedUICommand.CanExecute()* returns false. But I want the buttons to check if the Admission is granted and to turn invisible if so. I want a generic solution, which works for all controls, which do have commands.

Comment: Have you tried to bind visibility of the button based on `elementName="yourButton" Value="IsEnabled"`?

Comment: Is the permission mode application-wide? I.e. are all affected commands forbidden/allowed at the same time? If yes, you could bind the `Visibility` property of the controls to an application-wide static property.

Comment: fmunkert: True, but I think the restriction is an issue of the commands. So they should now when they can be executed and the controls should only hide, if they can't be executed.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Button` already becomes disabled you can make `Visibility` dependant on `IsEnabled` property

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

or you could make use of [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to do the same instead of using `Trigger`

```
<Button ... Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

**EDIT**

If these properties are independent then you still can do it via `Binding` and `Converter`

```
<Button ... Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Command.Admission, FallbackValue=Visible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

this code will bind `Visiblity` to `Command.Admission` via `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` converter and if the value cannot be retrieved, because it's not `RestrictedRoutedUICommand` or `Command` is not assigned, then `FallbackValue` will be use

Comment: I don't want to use the *RoutedUICommand.CanExecute()*. Because CanExecute() should only determine, if it is possible to execute the command. So I added another method to the RoutedUICommand which determines if the command is allowed, I want the controls to use this one.

Comment: So they are not related? But if the command is not allowed then it cannot be executed.

Comment: I still want the controls to turn grey, when the command can not be executed because of a missing parameter. But I want them to hide, if the command is forbidden. 
I just want to know how it is implemented, that they turn grey, when a command can't be executed. So I can implement it the same way for my issue.

Comment: Check my edit. There is no way to do it automatically but you can still do it via binding

Comment: @cix very good decision. The UI should be consistent within a session, not having things amgically disappear. See that too often, sadly.

Comment: @dkozl, it sure works. But then I had to add this code in each button... is there a shorter way? I could create sub classes for Button, MenutItem...

Comment: You could create `Style(s)` for `ButtonBase` and `MenuItem`.